# Else doesn't work in reader using c#

Tags: c#

When I enter user name and password, it logs in successfully and also opens desired field but when I enter wrong name or password (not saved in DB) it shows nothing actually it should encounter "else" this is the code

```
private void signin_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= D:/Student_Managment_System/SMS1.mdb";

     OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
     myConnection.Open();

     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
     cmd.Connection = myConnection;

     string usrname = name_textBox.Text;
     string passwd = pass_textBox.Text;

     OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select * from Manager where Name='" + usrname + "' and Passwd='" + passwd + "'");

     OleDbDataReader Reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

     while (Reader.Read())
     {
          if (Reader[5].ToString() == "manager")
          {
              this.Hide();
              Student_Info stuInf = new Student_Info();
              stuInf.Show();
              break;
          }
          else if (Reader[5].ToString() == "employee")
          {
              MessageBox.Show("log in as a employee ");
          }
          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Inviled User name or password");
          }
     }

     myConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `else` statement isn't executed because there are no values to read when an invalid username or password is entered. You need to check if your reader has any rows. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Code**

```
//Are there any rows
if(Reader.HasRows)
{
    //If so read them
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        if (Reader[5].ToString() == "manager")
        {
            this.Hide();
            Student_Info stuInf = new Student_Info();
            stuInf.Show();
            break;
        }
        else if (Reader[5].ToString() == "employee")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("log in as a employee ");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Inviled User name or password");
}
```